# Working Space in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

OSX and Linux, have the concept of "Working Space", where we can switch between 4 working spaces.

Is there any way to have multiple "Working spaces" in Windows 7? Any software that we can install to get the same effect, look and feel.

Comment: I have no idea what "Working Space" is. Can you post a link that explains this in Linux?

Comment: @Magicandre1981 it is essentially a Windows desktop - each user can have multiple desktops with different settings, shortcuts, backgrounds, etc.

Comment: in this case the topic must be closed as off topic. Product recommendation is off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about something like Mac's Spaces, then try this:

SysInternals Desktops: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx]

Image from the website:

[image: Image from the website]